# android - unexpected brief orientation change at switch of activity

Tags: android

I want to set the orientation of the screen dynamically in my android application. For that I use

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT));
```

and alike. That works fine so far yet I experience occasionally an unwanted brief switch of orientation when going from one activity to the next. The problem occurs when I hold the device in a manner which would let the sensor set the orientation differently to the programatically chosen one.

I was able to reproduce the problem in the following simple application which basically consists of two activities letting the user switch to the other activity through pressing a button. For the sake of simplicity I set the orientation in the activities always to landscape yet please have in mind that what I need is to choose the orientation at runtime so moving the orientation setting to the manifest wouldnt do for me.

Any suggestion how to avoid this unwanted occasional screen orientation switch would be great.

Thanks

martin

```
public class A_Activity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_a);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_a);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(A_Activity.this, B_Activity.class));
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

}
}
```

The second activity - B_Activity - is defined just in the same manner starting A_Activity on button press

The layouts are as simple as

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_a"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Click A" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.switchactivitytest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".A_Activity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="A Activity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".B_Activity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="B Activity" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this in for your activity in the manifest rather than programmatically change the orientation

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Comment: as I wrote -  I need is to choose the orientation at runtime - so this wont do for me

Comment: yet thanks for the reply - I actually wrote wrongly "moving the orientation setting to the layout wouldnt do for me." I changed it to what I had in mind, "moving the orientation setting to the manifest wouldnt do for me."